# phpmailler erro ao enviar email

Tags: php, phpmailer

como posso enviar mais de um 'email' com o 'phpmailler' ele sempre da esse erro 'Mail error: You must provide at least one recipient email address.' estou desenvolvendo um sistema de newsletter que ira selecionar todos os 'email' cadastrado mas ele sempre da isso.
detalhe eu pego os emails por uma 'variavel' e passo ela para o envio de quem ira receber os emails.

meu codigo:

```
$nome       = "leonardo";   // Pega o valor do campo Nome
$assunto    = "sadasdsad";  // Pega o valor do campo Telefone
$email      = "sadsadas@dsadasd.com";   // Pega o valor do campo Email
$mensagem   = "asdasdsadsadsadsad"; // Pega os valores do campo Mensagem

// Variável que junta os valores acima e monta o corpo do email

$Vai        = "Nome: $nome\n\nE-mail: $email\n\nAssunto: $assunto\n\nMensagem: $mensagem\n";


require_once("phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php");
$mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost","root", "", "projeto") or die(mysqli_connect_error());
$query = "SELECT * FROM newsletter";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
$emails = array();
while($row = $result->fetch_array()){
   $emails[] = $row['mail'];
}

define('GUSER', 'gmail@gmail.com'); // <-- Insira aqui o seu GMail
define('GPWD', 'gmail123');     // <-- Insira aqui a senha do seu GMail

function smtpmailer($para, $de, $de_nome, $assunto, $corpo) { 
    global $error;
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP();        // Ativar SMTP
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;       // Debugar: 1 = erros e mensagens, 2 = mensagens apenas
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;     // Autenticação ativada
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';  // SSL REQUERIDO pelo GMail
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com'; // SMTP utilizado
    $mail->Port = 465;          // A porta 587 deverá estar aberta em seu servidor
    $mail->Username = GUSER;
    $mail->Password = GPWD;
    $mail->SetFrom($de, $de_nome);
    $mail->Subject ="gmail - Contato";
    $mail->Body = $corpo;
    if(count($para) > 1){
      foreach($para as $email){
        $mail->AddAddress($email);
      }
    }else{
        $mail->AddAddress($para);
      }

    if(!$mail->Send()) {
        $error = 'Mail error: '.$mail->ErrorInfo; 
        return false;
    } else {
        $error = 'Mensagem enviada!';
        return true;
    }
}
var_dump($emails);
// Insira abaixo o email que irá receber a mensagem, o email que irá enviar (o mesmo da variável GUSER), 
//o nome do email que envia a mensagem, o Assunto da mensagem e por último a variável com o corpo do email.

 if (smtpmailer($emails, '$email', '$nome', '$assunto', $Vai)) {


    echo"<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert(\"Sua Mensagem foi Enviada com Sucesso!\");
            history.go(-1);
         </script>\n";

}
if (!empty($error)) echo $error;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para acertar sua função, acerte primeiramente o array de emails, o código abaixo vai armazenar apenas o primeiro email do banco de dados.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM newsletter";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
$row = $result->fetch_array();
$mail = $row['mail'];
```

Mude o código para:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM newsletter";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
$emails = $result->fetch_all();
```

ou ainda:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM newsletter";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
$emails = array();
while($row = $result->fetch_array()){
   $emails[] = $row['mail'];
}
```

Para enviar o mesmo email para várias pessoas é necessário fazer um foreach iterando `$emails` e dentro do laço chame `AddAddress`

mude:

```
$mail->AddAddress($para);
```

para:

```
if(count($para) > 1){
  foreach($para as $email){
    $mail->AddAddress($email);
  }
}else{
    $mail->AddAddress($para);
}
```

e a chamada deve ficar assim:

```
if (smtpmailer('$para', '$email', '$nome', '$assunto', $Vai)) {
```

A linha `$to = array($mail);` não é mais necessária.

Comment: eu fiz do modo que voce falou e deu erro Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\novo\enviar_email.php on line 38 vou editar a perg com o codigo que voce descreveu

Comment: arrumei o erro do else voce mas ainda continua o erro Mail error: You must provide at least one recipient email address.

Comment: resolvi os erro e deu certo foi vou editar a perg e deixar a resposta pra quem precisar usar

Comment: @LeonardoCosta, agora que vi os comentários, as chaves estão erradas mesmo, vou corrigir isso.

Answer (score 0):

Não passe o email como array, passe como CSV, valores separados por virgula:

```
teste@google.com, alan@google.com
```

Para transformar o array `$to` em CSV utilize a função `implode`

```
$to = array($mail);
$to = implode($to, ",");
```

Comment: mas os email vem cadastrado do banco como que eu vou pegar todos os cadastrado sem ser com array?

Comment: eles vem em que formato do banco de dados? da um exemplo.

Comment: Se você tem array da um `implode($to, ",");`

Comment: ah to intendendo inserir , neles seria isso?

Comment: Editei a resposta da uma olhada

Comment: tentei fazer isto mas continua no erro

Comment: dei um var dump nele e olha o que ele me traz tenho 2 email no banco  string(29) "testando@test.com" Mail error: You must provide at least one recipient email address.